# Java 17/Mac OS Java2D Queue Flusher Crash

Tags: java

Anybody else having this crash on macOS + JDK17?

OS Version:            macOS 11.6 (20G165)
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (17.0+35) (build 17+35-2724)

```
Thread 23 Crashed:: Java: Java2D Queue Flusher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2040392e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff204325bd pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff20387406 abort + 125
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001058d13e1 os::abort(bool, void*, void const*) + 49
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000105aabecc VMError::report_and_die(int, char const*, char const*, __va_list_tag*, Thread*, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, int, unsigned long) + 2908
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000105aab345 VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, ...) + 149
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000105aabf61 VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, void*, void*) + 33
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010597a07b JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 363
8   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff20477d7d _sigtramp + 29
9   ???                             0x00007ffffffffff8 0 + 140737488355320
10  com.apple.AMDRadeonX5000MTLDriver   0x000000012ad40801 void amdMtl_HWL_SetTexture<(AMDMtl_SqttMode)0>(GFX9_RenderCmdEncoderMembersRec*, unsigned int, id<MTLTexture>, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 91
11  libawt_lwawt.dylib              0x000000011b2ecf91 MTLVertexCache_FlushGlyphVertexCache + 81
12  libawt_lwawt.dylib              0x000000011b2ea406 MTLTR_DrawGlyphList + 4022
13  libawt_lwawt.dylib              0x000000011b2e4cc4 Java_sun_java2d_metal_MTLRenderQueue_flushBuffer + 5236
14  ???                             0x00000001119111d5 0 + 4589687253
15  ???                             0x0000000111cf628c 0 + 4593771148
```

any clue what can be causing this and how to avert it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the error well, but you can probably prevent it (or at least get a different error) with this argument:

`java -Dsun.java2d.metal=false`

The Metal pipeline is the default on Mac as of a few years ago, and if you toggle it off you can switch to the older OpenGL pipeline.

(I'm exploring a similar-but-different crash that includes `Java_sun_java2d_metal_MTLRenderQueue_flushBuffer`, although the rest of our stacktraces differ.)

See also:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-4718

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8284381

Comment: Hopefully they fixed it by now, we're now using JDK 19.

However, I might try turning of java2d.metal like you suggest and see if our app renders correctly.

Our current jvm launcher does indeed turn java2d.metal on

appendJvmOption(&extraJvmOptions, "-Dsun.java2d.metal=true", NULL);